# Sample point elevation from a given contour

Tags: qgis, raster, contour, sample

I need to sample the elevation at number of predefined location given in CSV format (but could convert to shapefile if needed). My input data is a shapefile of contour lines.

Is it possible to sample the elevation directly? Possibly having to converting the contour to a DEM or other sort of raster.

I've seen many questions regarding the opposite transformation (points to contour) but I can't seem to have been able to find this one.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are after, some GRASS modules might be helpful. These can be found in menu processing > processing tool box:

[image]

To compute a raster dem I made good experience with the grass module `v.surf.rst`. This is a bit tricky (lots of parameters...), but the background is described in detail by the authors MITASOVE & HOFIERKA in this paper: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~hmitaso/gmslab/papers/MG-II-93.pdf

Once having your DEM ready, you can use `v.sample` so sample your DEM at given locations. For this you first need to make point locatins from your csv. Use the QGIS text file import capabilities for this:

[image]

Use these points as input to Grass-module `v.sample`. This creates a new points file with an additional attribute containing your sampled raster values. Right click on it in the layer tree and `Save as...` csv.

For further use you can put this all together with the graphical modeler.